# Is it possible to have copyright on a TV show format?

Tags: copyright

There was the TV show "TV total Deutscher Eisfußball-Pokal" (TV total German ice soccer cup) by Stefan Raab and the last episode is from 2015. See [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_total_Deutscher_Eisfu%C3%9Fball-Pokal)

Now someone wanted to make a similar show "Kick auf Eis" (kick on ice) in 2022. But now they got a warning from the lawyer of Raab and so they won't make the show. He claims it's a copy of his show. See [this news](https://www.ingame.de/news/streaming/trymacs-stefan-raab-streamer-kick-auf-eis-streit-abmahnung-fussball-twitch-hamburg-91939369.html)

I am less interested in if this is justified (the warning by the lawyer).

I am more interested in what the basis for such a warning is. Is it copyright?

Does Stefan Raab have a copyright on the show format?

When you paint a picture you automatically obtain copyright on it.

This might be the same for the video material of a single show.

But did Stefan Raab automatically obtain copyright on the whole TV show format?

If not what is the legal basis for the warning?

Answer (score 3):

The argument would have to be either a derivative work under copyright, or a trade dress/trademark claim.

Neither sounds very solid at all.

Neither copyright nor trade dress/trademark protect ideas like a TV format. They can only protect very similar expressions of an idea that necessarily flow one from the other and, for example, the game mechanics can't be protected by copyright.